# Многопоточная работа apt-get

Tags: linux, apt-get

Есть новая рабочая машина, постепенно устанавливаю нужный софт. Для установки использую apt-get, некоторые пакеты `.deb` и `.run` качаю и устанавливаю через Ubuntu Software Center.

Я определенно могу выполнять `apt-get install` в нескольких инстансах терминала одновременно, но стоит ли так делать? Может ли привести к ошибкам при установке?

Можно ли одновременно выполнять `apt-get install` и установку через Software Center?

Comment: Если пакеты независимые  - то да, можно. Но на практике так лучше не делать. 

Некоторые пакетные менеджеры делают лок, поэтому, даже если запустить в паралель, все равно будет работать последовательно. Делает ли его apt - я не знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно дать команду на установку нескольких пакетов сразу:

```
$ sudo apt-get install пакет1 пакет2 ...
$ sudo dpkg -i файл1 файл2 ...
```

---

установка пакета — это не атомарное действие, а состоит из нескольких взаимосвязанных, поэтому при вызове всех упомянутых программ они устанавливают блокировку, препятствующую одновременному запуску нескольких экземпляров программ, вносящих изменения в пакетную базу.

*ubuntu software center*, как и прочие графические обёртки вокруг пакетной базы, для непосредственных манипуляций (в зависимости от реализации) либо напрямую вызывают упомянутые программы, либо действуют через библиотечные функции, и в конечном итоге тоже устанавливают ту же самую блокировку.

---

небольшое отступления с изложением некоторых подробностей:

`apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` — собственно установкой пакета не занимаются, а предназначены для:

- взаимодействия с репозиториями: скачивания списков пакетов и файлов с пакетами
- разрешения зависимостей и конфликтов на основе информации из списков пакетов и из уже установленных пакетов
- принятия решений о том, какие именно пакеты устанавливать, какие удалять, какие обновлять

а собственно для установки/удаления/обновления пакетов эти программы вызывают уже `dpkg`, чей алгоритм работы достаточно сложен и подробно изложен в [документации](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html).

многие из всех выше-перечисленных действий (выполняемых как `apt*`, так и `dpkg`), будучи выполнены одновременно в произвольном порядке, могут приводить к конфликтам и несогласованности. потому одновременный запуск этих программ нежелателен и (где возможно) запрещается блокировками.

---

доп. информация из [Часто задаваемые вопросы о Debian GNU/Linux](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/index.ru.html):

- [Основы системы управления пакетами Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.ru.html)
- [Инструменты управления пакетами Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.ru.html)
- [Поддержание обновлений системы Debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-uptodate.ru.html)

Comment: про установку нескольких пакетов знаю, но не всегда это удобно, могу заранее не знать полный список того, что нужно установить. Но в целом понял, спасибо за подробный ответ.